# Create list out of set

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, set

I am reading *Dive into Python3* book and following examples. In chapter 2 , *Native Datatypes* I am trying , like in example to create list out of set.

```
a_list = ['a', 'b', 'mpilgrim', True, False, 42]
a_set = set(a_list)                           
a_set
```

But I am getting `TypeError`:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 TypeError: 'set' object is not callable
```

Can someone help me to see why?

Comment: Did you assign anything to `set` before?

Comment: No.. I see it now. Thank you for your help. And thank you for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhere else in your code, above those lines shown, you must have done this:

```
set = {...}
# or
set = set(...)
```

Doing this overshadowed the built-in `set` with a user defined name.  So, the name `set` now refers to a set *instance* and not the class:

```
>>> set # Built-in
<class 'set'>
>>> set() # Is callable
set()
>>> set = {1, 2, 3} # Built-in is overshadowed
>>> set
{1, 2, 3}
>>> set() # Is no longer callable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'set' object is not callable
>>>
```

You need to find where you did this and pick a different name.

Comment: Thank you.. I am confused for downvetes. Stackoverflow is for amaters and people that learn too.

Comment: Indeed.  But sometimes people downvote questions that they consider to be just stupid mistakes.  You can't stop that since people may downvote for whatever reason they choose.  I would just dust off and move on.  After all, it's just magical Internet points. :)